# Get text from texteditor with laravel 5

Tags: php, html, laravel

I would like to get the html code of a texteditor.

I use this texteditor http://adminbootstrap.com/wb/right/0.3.0/texteditor.html .

I've a form with the texteditor inside it but when I would like to get the html code with:

```php
$request->input('texteditor');
```

It doesn't work and whereas I gave a name to the texteditor,

What is going wrong?

My view code:

```
<form>
<div class="container-fluid half-padding">
    <div class="pages pages_dashboard">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-warning">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h3 class="panel-title">Contenu de l'actualitée</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="template template_texteditor">
                  <div class="summernote"></div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

And

```
<div class='summernote'></div>
```

dynamically creating other div and the html code is contained in

```
<div class='note-editable panel-body' name='texteditor'></div>
```

[image: texteditor code]

**EDIT 1**

Another way :

```
$('.summernote').summernote('code');
```

to get the entire html code of summernote texteditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have no textarea form field that is being sent back to the server that contains the wanted content.

The simple thing would be to change

```
 <div class='note-editable panel-body' name='texteditor'></div>
```

to

```
 <textarea class='note-editable panel-body' name='texteditor'></textarea>
```

or run some javascript on form submit to add this as post['textarea']  from the TEXT of the div content

Comment: but i would like to get html tags also

Comment: then you will need to listen on submit to the form with Javascipt, and then put the html of the texteditor into post var texteditor

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097184/pass-extra-variable-when-submitting-a-form-using-jquery 

where the value would be $("div[name='texteditor']).html();